# Customizing CSS counters in ordered lists

Tags: html, css

I want to create two ordered (independent of each other) HTML lists that have the following formats and start at the numbers, as presented here:

```
2.1 
2.2
2.3
2.4


2.1.1
2.1.2

2.2.1
2.2.2
2.2.3

2.3.1
2.3.2

2.4.1
2.4.2
```

How do I do this with CSS?

Any help would be appreciated as I have exhausted resources here in trying to figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried anything? Show us your work, e.g. using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I used a hanging indent to align text following manual input of list numbers as noted above, but I am looking for an automatic means of consecutive numbering.

Comment: .hangingindent {
    padding-left: 44px;
    text-indent: -44px;
}

<p class="hangingindent">2.1.1&nbsp;&nbsp;blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>

Comment: You may use `counter-reset` and `li:before` like the way I showed on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: firststlevel; 
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(firststlevel);
  counter-increment: firststlevel;
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
}
ol ol {
  counter-reset: secondlevel;
}
ol ol li:before{
  content:counter(firststlevel) "."counter(secondlevel);
  counter-increment: secondlevel;
}

ol ol ol {
   counter-reset: thirdlevel;
}
ol ol ol li:before{
  content:counter(firststlevel) "."counter(secondlevel)"."counter(thirdlevel);
  counter-increment: thirdlevel;
  text-indent:-5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Main 1</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Child 1 of Main 1
        <ol>
            <li>Sub Child 1 of Child 1 of Main 1</li>
            <li>Sub Child 1 of Child 1 of Main 1</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Child 2 of Main 1
             <ol>
            <li>Sub Child 1 of Child 2 of Main 1</li>
            <li>Sub Child 2 of Child 2 of Main 1</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <li>Main 2</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Child 1 of Main 2
            <ol>
            <li>Sub Child 1 of Child 1 of Main 2</li>
            <li>Sub Child 2 of Child 1 of Main 2</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Child 2 of Main 2
             <ol>
            <li>Sub Child 1 of Child 2 of Main 2</li>
            <li>Sub Child 2 of Child 2 of Main 2</li>
            <li>Sub Child 3 of Child 2 of Main 2</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start for me as I am trying to understand how counter resets work. I don't, however, want a main level. The start of my list level is 2.1.1 at the first level, not the second. Can you help further?

Comment: ok here is the fiddle link [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/soumyakolkata/DepAv/1/)